# Excel - Retrieve number from end of cell and move to start

Tags: excel, vba, numbers, move

I have an outputted excel table that has addresses in single cells in one column but the house number is at the end of the cell value.

```
AAA Street 10
BBB Street 11
```

Is there a script that if a cell contains a number it will grab this number and place it at the start of the cell so it looks like:

```
10 AAA Street
11 BBB Steet
```

I have a system that generates this information into address labels but my countries postal service requires the number at the start.

Comment: Is there always going to be one space before the number at the end of each address? For example, will *Street* always have one space after it before the house number?

Comment: yes, the formatting will be consistent in that respect

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to your question?

Answer (score 0):

It's *incredibly* convoluted, but one way you could go about this is to use the following formula to get what you're looking for:

```
=RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE($A2," ","/",LEN($A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A2," ",""))),LEN($A2)-SEARCH("/",SUBSTITUTE($A2," ","/",LEN($A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A2," ","")))))&" "&LEFT(SUBSTITUTE($A2," ","/",LEN($A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A2," ",""))),SEARCH("/",SUBSTITUTE($A2," ","/",LEN($A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A2," ",""))))-1)
```

[image]

Personally, I would assign the following part to a *defined name* and use that in the formula instead:

`SUBSTITUTE($A2," ","/",LEN($A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A2," ","")))`

Doing so would just make it a lot easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

You might not have the numbers at the end of each cell to search.  Here's a formula that checks the last five characters for a space and if none will leave the cell alone else will swap what's found.

=IF(IFERROR(FIND(" ",MID(A2,LEN(A2) -5,50)),0)=0,A2,MID(A2,LEN(A2) - (FIND(" ",MID(A2,LEN(A2) -5,50)) -1),40) & " " & MID(A2,1,LEN(A2) - FIND(" ",MID(A2,LEN(A2) -5,50))))

Answer (score 0):

a VBA solution:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim element As Variant

    With Worksheets("MySheetName") ' change "MySheetName" to your actual sheet name
        For Each cell In .Range("A1:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row) ' loop through columns A cells from row 1 down to last not empty one
            For Each element In Split(cell.value, " ") 'loop through current cell content string "elements" separated by spaces
                If IsNumeric(element) Then ' if current element is a "numeric" one
                    cell.value = element & " " & Replace(cell.value, element, "") 'move element at the beginning of the cell content
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```